# CSS styles and JS files are not uploading on to the production server

Tags: javascript, css, drupal-7

When I add new CSS styles and JS files to the production server, the new files are not uploading on to the production server, but it is uploaded on the development server and working fine. The CSS styles and JS files I added are correct, because they are working on the development server.

--any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this question belong at `http://drupal.stackexchange.com/`?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs A thousand times no, we don't deal with questions about FTP uploads

Answer (score 1):

use api's  then or upload them to any other server and get the link

and elaborate some more 
then we will help you more